# adf skin: inputText

Tags: oracle-adf, skin

how to change the color when I select the inputText? I wanted it to be gray but already shifted at all border color (content: busy, focus, edit) and does not change.

can someone help me?

Comment: Please improve your question. It is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what do you mean by 'remains' you should use something like this (when using ADF Skinning):

```css
af|inputText::content,
af|inputText::content:selected,
af|inputText::content:focus,
af|inputText::content:hover,
{
 border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello, 

how to change the color when I select the inputText? I wanted it to be gray but already shifted at all border color (content: busy, focus, edit) and does not change. 

can someone help me?